# Converting millisecond coordinates to decimal cords. C#

Tags: c#, coordinates

I have this code which converts N052.39.51 format, but i need more precision so i need to convert N052.39.51.884.

```
    public double ToDecimleCoordDouble(double degrees, double minutes, double seconds)
    {
        return degrees + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600);
    }
```

Comment: Well, start by adding that extra parameter. And btw, I think that `int` would be clearer than `double` for the parameters here. Not easier or faster, just clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure if there are some "milliseconds" for angles. But if they do exist then there are definitely 3 600 000 milliseconds in a degree.
You can easily add an extra argument to your function this way:

```
public double ToDecimleCoordDouble(int degrees, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)
{
    return degrees + (minutes / 60.0) + (seconds / 3600.0) + (milliseconds / 3600000.0);
}
```

And, yes, you better use `int` because, in your case, the next argument already covers the fractional part and there couldn't be double values. 
I mean, there shouldn't be "61.5 degrees and 5.5 minutes" because it should be "61 degree, 35 minutes and 30 seconds".

Answer (score 1):

Seconds can have fractional parts, but the math is the same, just pass `51.884` as the seconds parameter.

Since degrees and minutes can't have fractional parts in that form, I'd consider making those two parameters `int`.